# How to convert bignumber to normal number using ethers.js?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, ethers.js, bignumber

I am using ethers.js I can't figure out how do you convert a bignumber like 1252500000000000000 to 125.25

-Mike

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I was able to use `ethers.utils.formatEther( value ) ⇒ string` to convert back to readable.

Comment: Notice that this assumes you are formatting a number with 18 decimals (like eth itself, or most ERC20 tokens). If you wanted to format a token with a different number of decimals (like USDC, which has 6), you need to use `ethers.utils.formatUnits(value, 6)`. `formatEther` is a shorthand for `formatUnits(value, 18)`.

Comment: I have a number that shows as `512` in the etherscan. 0.000000000000000512

Comment: current the above returns a tiny number, is there a way to convert a uInt? now i'm doing this:
`Math.round(parseFloat(str) * (10 ** 18))`

Comment: The key is to keep track the amount of decimal places when working with various tokens, as they might be different and might require different conversion from wei.  I had a problem that my approval was for a 18 d.p. number while this ballance indeed didnt exist!

Answer (score 5):

```
const BigNumber = require('bignumber.js');

let num=new BigNumber(1252500000000000000)
let denom = new BigNumber(10).pow(16)
let ans = num.dividedBy(denom).toNumber()
console.log(ans)
```

Hope this explains your question.For further info,refer https://mikemcl.github.io/bignumber.js/

Comment: This returns NaN

Comment: I use web3js for above snippet.Sorry i didn't notice etherjs in your question earlier

Answer (score 0):

parseFloat(value);
I have to put in 18 more characters

Answer (score 0):

For hexadecimal values you can also directly use ethers.utils.formatEther(_hex)

so if the value is 0x3635c9adc5dea00000 ( equals to 1000 * 18**10 ) you can parse it to ether by directly passing it to formatEther